# What is this reflection on the wall of a glass?

Tags: optics, reflection, geometric-optics

How does this work? Why are there multiple reflections? And why are the "inner" ones smaller?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically this picture attempts to explain why you see the label multiple times, in terms of a red dot painted on the glass that you would see multiple times.
[image]

This works even better if the glass is thicker at the bottom, which I suspect it is, but it's not strictly neccessary. If it's thicker at the bottom you might be benefitting from a phenomenon called "total internal reflection" - when you consider light leaving a medium where light moves more slowly, there is a minimum angle where, if light hits the glass at a more shallow angle than that, it is guaranteed to reflect. You can see this when you dive underwater and look up, at certain angles, you see reflections of the bottom of the pool. The reason it happens only if the glass is getting thicker is that a ray coming from your eye, refracting on the outside edge of the glass, then hitting the inside edge of the glass, will hit the inside edge of the glass at a shallower angle, and that angle might be below the total internal reflection threshold. In whether or not you're benefitting from this phenomenon, it remains true that at shallower angles *more* of the light will reflect, so it makes sense the only works at high angles.

As for why the image gets smaller and smaller, its because the surfaces of the glass are curved. Now consider this picture to see why subsequent reflections look smaller. The two tick marks on the outside of the glass represent the edges of the label.
[image]